# egrep specific paragraph from search string to origin string before

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

Right now, I am searching through 3.297 GZIP archived log files with following command:

```
zegrep -B 60 -E 'DMAStatus.*nError\ {13}.{3,5}\ $' collector_2018-*
```

What I would like to realize:
To replace the option
`-B 60`
with a specific search pattern.

That means, right now I extract 60 lines before every search result. However, 60 lines might be way too little but also way too much. (Depending on what, or rather how many lines are written into the log before the
   `'DMAStatus.*nError\ {13}.{3,5}\ $'`
is recorded)

BTW, the ending pattern: `'\ {13}.{3,5}\ $'` is just a specific string I am looking for at the end of files.

`\ {13}` = Look for 13 White-space characters

`.{3,5}` = Look for any string within 3-5 characters length

`\ $'` = Followed by one more single White-space character ending with EOL $

I know that every error message is invoked by one specific character set: `01TNL`

How can I run the `zegrep` command to search for the search pattern given above, and then print any line starting from `01TNL` to the search pattern?

I add here an example of four different log files, copied together into one file in Notepad++.
I forgot to add some crucial information, unfortunately. I am afraid, this is also why the approach by using `awk` didn't work out well.

The string `01TNL` appears several times in each log file. If the string is constantly `01TNL000`, it is no error and the log file keeps on growing.
Any other combination than three times `000` is processed as error.
Log files with no error at the end should be ignored, for any other cases all the log file information from, e.g. line `01TNL020` to the ending line `DMAStatus->nError` and everything in between should be printed.

```
############   Logfile 2018-10-16_10-23-25 started pid 88108  
10:23:53.987   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
10:24:12.803   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
10:24:30.934   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
10:24:49.040   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL0**2**0"  
10:24:49.702   DMSG: DMAStatus->nError             2329


############   Logfile 2018-10-17_20-35-08 started pid 187491  
20:36:47.838   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
20:36:53.487   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
20:36:58.418   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
20:37:02.329   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
21:24:51.060   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
21:24:54.864   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
21:24:58.773   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
21:25:03.175   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
21:25:03.340   DMSG: DMAStatus->nError             0 


############   Logfile 2018-10-15_18-45-08 started pid 42128  
18:46:49.656   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:46:55.980   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:47:01.407   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:47:05.266   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:47:09.130   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:52:57.211   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:53:01.146   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:53:05.006   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:53:09.611   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
18:53:16.078   DMSG: DMAStatus->nError             0 


############   Logfile 2018-10-18_03-32-00 started pid 12504  
03:33:52.948   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL000"  
03:33:55.429   FIO:  rcvd ".01TNL00**1**"  
03:34:01.823   DMSG: DMAStatus->nError             2288
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grep is the wrong tool. Awk would be a better fit. Something like:

```
zcat foo.gz | awk '/^01TNL/, /DMAStatus.*nError {13}.{3,5} $/ { print }'
```

Edit: [more reading](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) on matching ranges in awk.

Comment: awk is probably one of the tools I use the most that I don't advokate.
grep is absolutely the correct tool. Just add -P and get it on.